# Angular bootstrap accordion stopped working on update

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have an accordion that has been working fine (ui.bootstrap). I ran a bower install to get an update of something, and suddenly it's kaput. I click on the header once, and it selects the text, then again and the accordion expands. But I can't make it collapse again.

The console log says:

> TypeError: Failed to execute 'requestAnimationFrame' on 'Window': The callback provided as parameter 1 is not a function.
>
> > at TypeError (native)
> >
> > at http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:11786:20
> >
> > at http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:4297:31
> >
> > at async (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:4132:13)
> >
> > at Object.$AnimateProvider.$get.removeClass (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:4264:9)
> >
> > at collapse (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js?body=1:40:20)
> >
> > at Object.fn (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js?body=1:53:13)
> >
> > at Scope.$get.Scope.$digest (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:12448:29)
> >
> > at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:12713:24)
> >
> > at done (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:8316:45)

Anyone had this? It's a rails + angular app. My bower json includes:

```
"dependencies": {
    "jquery": "2.1.3",
    "jquery-ui": "1.10.4",
    "angular": "1.3.8",
    "angular-route": "1.3.15",
    "angular-resource": "1.3.15",
    "angular-bootstrap": "0.13.0",
    "angular-ui-slider": "0.1.1",
    "angular-sanitize": "1.3.15",
    "ng-tags-input": "2.3.0",
    "angular-google-maps": "2.1.0",
    "angular-google-places-autocomplete": "0.2.5",
    "angular-scrollable-table": "latest",
    "moment": "2.10.2",
    "underscore": "1.8.3",
    "angularjs-google-directions": "latest"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue with angular 1.2.8 and ui-bootstrap 0.13.0... 
Reverting to ui-bootstrap#0.12.0 fixed the issue on my side!

FIY, ui-bootstrap 0.13.0 was tested with angular 1.3.13, so either downgrade ui-bootstrap or upgrade angular to a version mentioned above.